# Photoshop - Is there a way to go to the next data set with a script instead of export data sets

Tags: javascript, automation, action, photoshop

Is there a way to go to the next data set with a script instead of export data sets?

I'm having the problem that my data set psd's are 100 mb each and seeing I will have thousands
it will be too large to handle.

I have already decreased the size of my image, but the csv data gets copied into every file.
I also do not want to have to split up the csv's every time.

So I'm looking to have a way to go to the next data set to process them and save them out as png's.

Please any help with the issue would be welcome

Comment: What help do you need exactly? What have you tried, what didn’t work?

Comment: So I'm trying to get a script to go to the next dataset. Thats all the functionality it needs, the rest I could do myself. Its just because if i would save out psd's for each data set then it would be x times 100mb and it would not be a good idea as I would anyway need to process them again. Once I figure out a way to go to next data set I could do the rest of the processing (centering text box etc) and directly save as a png image.

Comment: I know how to manualy go to the next data set but its 300.000 files so...